# TS2531 with useRef

Tags: reactjs, tslint

I'm getting an issue TSLink throwing TS2531 (Object is possibly 'null'.) in a code on my project to the point I'm doing the most simple test to isolate the issue.

The point is that I testing the exact same code in a React + TS sandbox on codesandbox and it's working fine. Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";

export const SimpleComp = () => {
    const refName = React.useRef(null);

    const getValue = (): void => {
        if (refName.current !== null) {
            console.log(refName.current.value);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" ref={refName} />
            <button onClick={() => getValue()}>Get Value</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

My guess it that I can fix it on tsconfig.json, but I'm not sure of how, since I copied the same tsconfig.json from the codesandbox and I'm still having the same issue. BTW, I'm using webstorm.

Any idea of how to fix it?

PS: here is the link for my the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-franklin-ww4xk

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using locally?

Comment: Just updated to Version 3.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript can not infer what the reference will be for. You can pass in the `HTMLInputElement` for the `useRef<T>` generic function.

Change:

```
const refName = React.useRef(null);
```

To:

```
const refName = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

Comment: Ok, that's something I didn't paid attention, It's like the first time I use 'useRef', but it's the first time I had issues. 
Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I also never used hooks before, but without telling TypeScript what the `refName.current` reference will contain it can't really infer that it can be either `null` or `HTMLInputElement`.